# Javascript android project using Gradle

Tags: javascript, android, gradle

I have a javascript android project with react native where we are building an app. We are using gradle as a build tool, and when I run the code I get the following error. I have tried changing the SDK versions, uninstalling android and reinstalling, uninstalling the emulator and reinstalling, as well as many other things. Any help would be great.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
19 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 17 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple build operations failed.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.
> Cannot snapshot output property 'outputDirectory'.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 44s
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I have tried changing the SDK versions, uninstalling android and reinstalling, uninstalling the emulator and reinstalling, as well as many other things.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is a massive project and I don't think the issue is with the code itself. I am pretty sure the issue is with Gradle, but I have no idea how to fix it.